# Outlook 2013/2016 won't download email until restart Office 365

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a problem with Outlook 2013/2016 with mail box on Office 365.

When Outlook is set in buffer mode it downloads emails but has no local data, slow viewing, etc.

When in buffer mode Outlook only downloads email while starting, not when working.

- I tried to delete OST file, change profile
- Options>Advanced>Send/Receive from there Select edit. By default Outlook sets the account to "Download complete items including attachments for subscribed folders". I changed this to "Download headers for subscribed folders"
- OST file repair
- Reinstalled Office from 2013 to 2016

Email show up on Office 365 portal and phone but not in Outlook 2013/2016 on laptop.

System is Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: 1) What is *buffer mode*? Possibly **cached Exchange mode**? 2) Do you have [Work Offline](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-from-working-offline-to-online-2460e4a8-16c7-47fc-b204-b1549275aac9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) enabled?

Comment: You are right "cached Exchange mode" i use office365 and i didnt know how its called in eng, work offline u mean that outlook is in offline mode?

Comment: Read the article I linked to about Work Offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover and confirm the autodiscover is pointing towards the correct exchange server , should be the same as what was in the 12.0 folder office 2010 I presume. If it's incorrect could be your group policy isn't updating until outlook is restarted.